insert auto generated number of one column into another column
I have a database table with two columns
customer_id Number and first_name VARCHAR2
For customer_id, the number will be auto incremented.
I need first_name with the value of customer_id in a specific format.
See the below example:

If the customer_id is auto incremented to value 1, the first_name should be NAME-1
if the customer_id is auto incremented to value 2, the first_name should be with 'NAME-2'
The only feasible option I got so far is performing 3 SQL statements.
One for insert and the next one is to read the incremented value and perform update to the first_name column.
I greatly appreciate the help and guidance if anyone can suggest a better way of handling this in minimum possible SQL queries.

What problem are you solving by concatenating name and id? Why do you want to do that?

One option is to create an identity column (for the ID column) and a database trigger which sets first name to desired value.
Table:
SQL> create table test (customer_id number generated always as identity,
  2                     first_name varchar2(10));

Table created.

Trigger:
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_test
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.first_name := :new.first_name ||'-'|| :new.customer_id;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

Testing:
SQL> insert into test (first_name) values ('Scott');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (first_name) values ('Mike');

1 row created.

Result:
SQL> select * from test;

CUSTOMER_ID FIRST_NAME
----------- ----------
          1 Scott-1
          2 Mike-2

SQL>


Because the "NAME-1" string is derived, either use an expression:
select
  *,
  name || '-' || id as name_id
from mytable

or create a view:
create view mytable_x as (
  select
    id,
    name as raw_name,
    name || '-' || id as name,
    -- other columns
  from mytable
)


In Oracle, you can't use CONCAT with more than two arguments, use || instead.

select Customer_id
    , concat(first_name, CONCAT('-', customer_id)) as first_name
from Customers;

